# Displaying information when mouse gets over markers on a Google Map (with FusionTips javascript, or any other solution...)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables, api-key

**I am trying to get some information displayed when the mouse gets over markers on a Google map (without having to click on the marker).**

These markers and their information come from a Google fusion table, and this works OK.

Therefore I am trying to use the "FusionTips" library : http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontips/docs/reference.html

---

**Here is my page : http://Bus.w.pw/FusionTips.html (you can click on the markers)**

---

I get the following error : "error, code=403 message=Forbidden reason=forbidden" from fusiontips.js, line 308

Maybe this error is related to a "google API key" issue?

But as you can see I have tried to use a google API key in my code.

Therefore any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Best regards

Comment: the 2nd link is broken

Comment: @Dr.Molle Oops, sorry. The links works now.

Comment: Here is the example given by the library author :

Comment: Code :  http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontips/docs/examples.html

Comment: Result : http://gmaps-utility-gis.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fusiontips/examples/fusiontips.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download is not allowed in the fusion table. That is required to use the FusionTables API v1.0 to access the data.  Download needs to be allowed to use FusionTips.

Comment: Thank you very much, I would never have found alone, FusionTips works now, except... (see details below)

Comment: What details below?  Below what?

Comment: (Since I am a new StackOverflow member, I am only allowed to post an "answer" at least 8 hours after asking the question, so I'll post the details tomorrow...)

Comment: Is what you are going to post an answer?  Or an update to your question?  If it is an update to the question, edit the question to add the additional information.  If it is a new question, it should be a new question, not an answer to this one.

Comment: (I could post the details in "Comments", but it would be ugly and hard to read because apparently it is not possible to insert line breaks in Comments... (test : <br> <p>))